# How to send a URL from android to a MVC PHP framework?

Tags: php, android

I am using an MVC framework in PHP. This framework will be working as the back end that does the CRUD function.

At the moment, the android application is only able to take this type of URL "localhost/app/login.php", while to access the controller at the back end I will need to pass a URL like this "localhost/app/login/". The problem here is that when I pass the latter URL, it doesn't seem to do anything in the controller.

Where am I doing wrong? or How to send the correct URL to the controller so it can do the work?

Comment: For a better understandig of your issue, please post the relevant code.

Comment: What if you open it in the browser ? Does it work ?

Comment: first check whether you enable xampp or wamp server. and then check it in browser.